# Reading in an uneven file to a struct

Tags: c++, input, struct, fileinputstream

I know how to read in a normal file into a struct but how do I do a file that has an uneven amount of elements like

John Smith 56

Katie Smith 52 38

Jane Doe 89 28

Currently I am doing it where Names is my structure and totalnames is a vector of them.

```
Struct Names{
string first;
string last;
string age;
string age_registered;
};

Names name;


vector<Names> totalnames;

while (file >> names.first >> names.last >> names.age >> names.age_registered){

totalnames.push_back(names);

}
```

But this is not working because of the uneven number of elements in each row. How should I fix this?

Comment: Read a line with `std::getline`. Put the line into a `std::istringstream`. Read tokens with `>>` until there are no more tokens. Repeat until `getline` fails.

Comment: With the additional remark that you'll have to decide what to actually _do_ with incomplete lines. Leave `age_registered` alone? Set it to some default value? That's really your call.

Comment: You may want to choose a different word than "normal" to describe the files you know how to read. From one perspective, any file that you can read from a disk is "normal". (From the Linux perspective, a directory is one example of a file that is not a "normal" file. So is the keyboard.)

Comment: This isn't C++. Create [mcve]